# Spring Batch Unmarshal XML issue, ItemReader and ItemWriter

Tags: xml, spring-batch, unmarshalling

I can currently unmarshal the XML below with the no problem, but while I am reading the document I end up with a **PublicFigure** Object and the List of **Associate** items.

**Below Is my current implementation.**

**My Xml**

```
<PublicFigure id="101">
    <Associate id="102" ex="No" code="66"/>
    <Associate id="103" ex="No" code="22"/>
</PublicFigure>
<PublicFigure id="102">
    <Associate id="144" ex="No" code="56"/>
    <Associate id="155" ex="No" code="45"/>
</PublicFigure>
```

**PublicFigure Java Class**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "associate"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PublicFigure")
public class PublicFigure {

    @XmlElement(name = "Associate", required = true)
    protected List<Associate> associate;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected BigInteger id;

    //getters and setters
```

**Associate Java Class**

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "")
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Associate")
    public class Associate {

        @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
        protected BigInteger id;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "code", required = true)
        protected BigInteger code;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "ex", required = true)
        protected String ex;

        //getter and setters
```

Is there any to unmarshal this XML into and object like the one below. In other words, to endup with an Associate Object and the PublicFigure Object frombwhere I can fetch the ID when required. With the sample below I will get the Associate Objects but the PublicFigure will be NULL

**Unmarshal into something like below**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Associate")
public class Associate {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected BigInteger id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "code", required = true)
    protected BigInteger code;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ex", required = true)
    protected String ex;

    @XmlElement(name = "PublicFigure", required = true)
    protected PublicFigure publicFigure;
```

You might asking why I want to do this, well because of the Spring Batch  ItemReader and ItemWriter. My ItemWriter is expecting me to read chunks of 10 of Associates Objects (as these must go into the Database), where in each object I need to reference the Public Figure ID. Unmarshaling and endup with **PublicFigure** objects where each contains a list of **Associates** is fine but I am not sure how to handle the ItemPreparedStatementSetter, this way I will endup with let's say 10 chunks of PublicFigures instead of Associates. Where Each PublicFigure have a list of 20 associates(let's assume for the sake of the example) in that case a chunk of 10 inserts will become now a 10*20  = 200 inserts  - As I have to insert the Associates List. Home makes sense.

```
@Bean
    ItemReader<PublicFigure> customerItemReader() {
        StaxEventItemReader<PublicFigure> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/Test_file.xml"));
        xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("PublicFigure");

        Jaxb2Marshaller publicFigMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        publicFigMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(PublicFigure.class);

        xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(publicFigMarshaller);
        return xmlFileReader;
    }


@Bean
    ItemWriter<Associate> associateItemWriter(DataSource dataSource, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Associate> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

        databaseItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT);

        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Associate> associateItemPreparedStatementSetter = new PersonAssociationsPreparedStatementSetter();
        databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(associateItemPreparedStatementSetter);

        return databaseItemWriter;
    }


    @Bean
    Step associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep")
                .<Associate, Associate>chunk(10)
                .reader(associateItemReader())
                .writer(associateItemWriter(super.dataSource, super.namedParameterJdbcTemplate))
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to work in a opposite way: instead of use `PublicFigure` as root object I will use `Associate`.
`Associate` object contains a reference to `PublicFigure` parent but this reference is injected using a [`Jax2Marshaller.Listener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html#setMarshallerListener-javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.Listener-).
Listener should be pretty easy to write because you receive unmarshalled object and its parent as parameters

```
class PublicFigureAssociateListener implements Listener {
  afterUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
    if(target instanceof Associate) {
      ((Associate) target).publicFigure = (PublicFigure) parent;
    }
  }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "PublicFigure")
public class PublicFigure {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected BigInteger id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Associate", required = true)
    protected List<Associate> associate;    
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Associate")
public class Associate {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected BigInteger id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "code", required = true)
    protected BigInteger code;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ex", required = true)
    protected String ex;
    /* This propery will be injected using Marshaller.Listener` */
    public PublicFigure publicFigure;
}
```

So, your code will change according:

```
@Bean
ItemReader<PublicFigure> publicFigureItemReader() {
      StaxEventItemReader<PublicFigure> xmlFileReader = new 
      xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/Test_file.xml"));
      xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("PublicFigure");
      Jaxb2Marshaller publicFigMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
      publicFigMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Associate.class, PublicFigure.class);
      publicFigMarshaller.setUnmarshallerListener(new PublicFigureAssociateListener());
      xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(publicFigMarshaller);
}

@Bean
ItemReader<Associate> customerItemReader() {
  return new AssociateItemReader(new publicFigureItemReader());
}
```

**EDIT**

Listener doesn't works well so you can use a delegate `ItemReader` in this way:

```
class AssociateItemReader implements ItemReader<Associate> {
  private final ItemReader<PublicFigure> delegate;
  private ListItemReader l;

  AssociateItemReader(ItemReader<PublicFigure> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.l = new ListItemReader(Collections.emptyList());
  }
  Associate read() {
    Associate next = l.read();
    if(next == null) {
      PublicFigure pf = delegate.read();
      if(pf != null) {
        l = new ListItemReader(pf.getAssociates());
        next = l.read();
      }
    }
    return next;
  }
}
```

**Remember to register `publicFigureItemReader()` as stream in `associateXmlFileToDatabaseStep()` so SB can handle reader lifecycle.**

Comment: I got it but I am a bit confused on how my PublicFigureAssociateListener() should look like

Comment: @ That's exactly what i did, the listener is getting called but the PublicFigure object is still null

Comment: inside the Listener afterUnmarshal when I evaluate the  (Associate) target).publicFigure = (PublicFigure) parent; The target (Associate) have the expected values but the publicFigure/ parent is null

Comment: I have added the AssociateItemReader which I guess it acts as a custom ItemReader, I have registred the new reader as `@Bean
 AssociateItemReader iReader() {
  return new AssociateItemReader();
 }` , and call this into my step. On debug I see it goes in but the Associate is null, I mean it kinda make sense to be null because my associateItemWriter which I wrote initially is not being used anymore and is there where I setResource and the setClassesToBeBound. Unless I am doing smth wrong

Comment: just edited the answer above, have a read. No is not working> Most probably I am not using the AssociateItemReader suggested by you as it should.

Comment: nice job. Finally working. Last night I actually endup changing the writer and implemented a jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(); I was reading the Public figure object with the Associates and then I was passing in the Associates to the .batchUpdate();. However, your solution from a performance point of view is much better, this is why I wanted to get it to work. As I have nearly 350 files to unmarshal. I will mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: I just noticed that woth the current implementation it only reads the first node PublicFigure, after the first node it will stop. Any idea why?

Comment: I knew that the ItemReader is called multiple times and on each call the read() should return the next value and return null when all input data has been finished but I was struggling with the fix. Spot on again.Thanks